# How to Create a Hierarchy of Elements Generated Automatically in Sparx Enterprise Architect

Tags: uml, modeling, enterprise-architect

I am using Sparx Enterprise Architect for the modeling process.

I created a custom requirements toolbox which is called security requirements based on a list of security standards using MDG technology.

I would like to create a hierarchy of requirements once the user drag-and-drop the main element into the workspace all sub-elements (requirements) are displayed automatically.

How I can create or design something similar to this process.

Thanks,

Comment: The "Insert Related Elements" Feature has nothing to do with MDG. It's really not clear what you are trying to achieve here

Comment: I want to connect some elements together, once I drag and drop the main element the all sub-elements are displayed at the "insert related elements".

Comment: Then the MDG is completely unrelated, all elements with a relationship to your "main" element will be in the insert related elements window. This is part of the traceability features: http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/model_navigation/traceability.html and http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/13.0/modeling_tools/insertrelatedelements.html

Comment: I will check it, thank u sir for ur helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a `_subtypeProperty` in your metatype like described in [EA's documentation](http://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/12.1/building_models/supportedattributes_2.html)

As always with EA you need some try-and-error to get it working. You might compare with BPMN2 Activity which offers such a menu:

[image]

The according MDG is located under EA's program folder in the MDGTechnologies. Just find the string `_subtypeProperty` and following `taskType`.

Comment: Very different from what i thought he wants to do, good catch

Comment: @Hue That's what I thought. Hope it's what he wants :-)

Comment: Thank u sir for ur comment I will try and I will give you the feedback